# Impressão cupom java

Tags: java

Como faço impressão de cupom no java, tanto em impressora matricial, e tanto em impressora térmica não fiscal?

E abrangendo todas as fabricantes... Tem como?

A programação muda dependendo da fabricante?

Comment: Infelizmente sua dúvida está muito ampla para um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas. Tente começar algo por aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cupom+fiscal e à medida que for concentrando suas dúvidas em questões mais específicas, vá fazendo perguntas isoladas para cada passo do desenvolvimento. Aqui tem umas dicas pra elaborar sua pergunta: [Ask] - Se quiser detalhar melhor a pergunta atual, deixando mais claro o que você já sabe fazer e quais partes não sabe, você pode clicar em [editar] e acrescentar informações.

Comment: Então, não que nada sobre código, a minha dúvida é se eu preciso programar para cada fabricante de impressora não fiscal ou tem como abrangir todas, de apenas uma forma..

Answer (score 1):

Cada fabricante de impressora fiscal libera sua sdk para desenvolvedores. Você vai ter que desenvolver individualmente, pois as funções depende de como cada empresa montou. Se você fizer pra Daruma e Bematech você já vai ter abrangido boa parte do mercado. Mas ainda tem outras marcas como Elgin, etc.. A respeito de abranger todas as fabricantes você pode montar uma interface com alguns métodos padrões, mas existem muitos métodos e com assinaturas diferentes(Abre cupom, Fecha cupom, etc...), então acho melhor você implementar para essas duas marcas e depois aos poucos você avança o projeto.

Comment: Você pode começar pelo site da Daruma: http://www.desenvolvedoresdaruma.com.br/home/index.php

Answer (score 1):

A impressão de cupons depende de vários fatores e estado aonde é feita a venda, tentarei explicar de forma geral.

O cupom pode ser de 3 tipos:

1. Cupom Normal
2. NFC-e, Nota Fiscal de Consumir Eletrônica
3. SAT

Item 1 - Cupom normal, depende de uma impressora fiscal (lacrada). Cada fabricante libera uma DLL para envio de comandos para a impressora, simplificando o desenvolvimento. A lista de comandos deste tipo de impressora são teoricamente iguais entre modelos e fabricantes, porém muda somente o nome de cada função.

Item 2 e 3 - Pode ser impresso em qualquer tipo de impressora. Tem QRCode e outros elementos complexo, e se for usar impressora de cupom que não precisa ser lacrada, você terá que usar a DLL do fabricante, para ter acesso as funções.

#### Solução

Para fazer algo centralizado, você terá que fazer uma interface, com os comandos que você deseja utilizar e implementar para cada impressora utilizando a DLL do fabricante.

Lembrando que a DLL pode ser diferente entre modelos de impressora do mesmo fabricante.

Comment: cupom normal não precisa de DLL em quase todas as marcas, você pode comandar a impressora diretamente. A DLL é apenas um facilitador (exceto no caso do SAT, pois os burocratas - pra não falar outra coisa - em vez de criarem um protocolo padrão, determinaram que a interface é a DLL, atrelando o desenvolvedor a OSes específicos).

Comment: Entendi, no caso do SAT, li que as fabricantes do SAT são obrigadas a seguir uma padronização para as funções das DLLs. Supomos que programo para o SAT da Bematech, depois para funcionar o SAT da Dimep, por exemplo, basta trocar a DLL? Pois a assinatura das funções nas DLLs sao padronizadas...

Comment: @RodrigoLima isto mesmo. Você faz a interface única, e chama as mesmas funções em DLL diferentes. Mas o seu caso é impressão, então se for o item 1 ou 2 que coloquei, pode ser qualquer impressora, não precisa ser de cupom.

Comment: Entendi, então no caso se eu quiser fazer a impressão de um cupom não fiscal em uma impressora térmica não fiscal da Bematech e da Daruma, por exemplo, terei que programar para as duas DLLs?

Comment: @RodrigoLima desculpa a demora para responder, depende, mas com 95% de certeza sim. Pois o cupom de SAT e CF-e, possui QRCode e outras particularidades que somente a DLL do fabricante faz. Exemplo na empresa que trabalho, a gente manda para a impressora a imagem do QRCode que foi montada por fora. Por isto o uso de interfaces é tão importante neste projeto.

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso esse QRCode que foi gerado por fora é dependente da DLL da fabricante?

Comment: Neste caso não, porém foi usando outro recurso da DLL que é imprimir uma imagem. Mas teoricamente todas  as novas impressoras tem o suporte do QRCode, e este caso foi uma situação especial.